# How to implement IDCT (JPEG Compression) in JavaScript / Java?

Tags: javascript, java, compression, jpeg, dct

I need this formula for IDCT in Javascript:

[image: formula for IDCT]

This is the Inverse Discrete Cosine Transformation, used for the decoding of JPEG compressed images. My problem is that I have no idea how to implement it, I also cannot find any help elsewhere on the internet, there's literally no code for this. I found [this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/wOi0DLh3MZ) Java Code for the DCT. I tried changing the parameters and loops so that it fits the formula but the values are totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This function calculate one member of result table.

First argument of the function is table with DC/AC coefficients, second (x) and third (y) - row and column of a member in the result table. C_u and C_v is a(u) and a(v) on your picture. table[u][v] is F(u,v).

```
function IDCT(table, x, y){

let C_u = 0.0, C_v = 0.0;
let vSum = 0.0;
let result = 0.0;

for (let u = 0; u < 8; u++)
{
    for (let v = 0; v < 8; v++)
    {
        if (u == 0)
        {
            C_u = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(2);
        }
        else { C_u = 1.0;}

        if (v == 0)
        {
             C_v = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(2);
        }
        else {C_v = 1.0; }


        vSum += C_u * C_v * table[u][v]
        * Math.cos(((2 * x + 1) * u * Math.PI) / 16.0)
        * Math.cos(((2 * y + 1) * v * Math.PI) / 16.0);

    }

    result += vSum;
    vSum = 0;
}

result *= 0.25;
result = Math.trunc(result);

return result;
}
```

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to this question. You will want to delete it before you get downvotes. Either convert it to Java or JavaScript or expect to lose a bunch of reputation if you leave this as an answer. Lose enough and you won't be able to answer questions at all. While they mentioned that they couldn't find IDCT in other languages, the code title and tags specify Java and JavaScript so the answer needs to be one of those languages. I didn't vote your answer down but people are very likely to do so since it doesn't answer the question asked in the title or tags.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks.